# Converting a given formula to vb.net

Tags: vb.net, math

I have a given mathematical formula that I need to translate to VB.NET code, but I am not getting the expected result.
As I found in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.sin?view=netframework-4.8),
I have to convert the angle so that `Math.Sin`  works correctly.

[image]

```
Dim locC1 = 1
Dim locC2 = 0.5
Dim locA1 = 30
Dim locA2 = 60

Dim locOldAxisToAngleConversion = (Math.PI / 180) * locA1
Dim locNewAxisToAngleConversion = (Math.PI / 180) * locA2
Dim locCylSinus1 = locC1 * Math.Sin(2 * locOldAxisToAngleConversion)
Dim locCylSinus2 = locC2 * Math.Sin(2 * locNewAxisToAngleConversion)
Dim locCylCosinus1 = locC1 * Math.Cos(2 * locOldAxisToAngleConversion)
Dim locCylCosinus2 = locC2 * Math.Cos(2 * locNewAxisToAngleConversion)
Dim locFraction = (locCylSinus1 + locCylSinus2) / (locCylCosinus1 + locCylCosinus2)
Dim locNewAxis = 0.5 * Math.Atan((Math.PI / 180) * locFraction)
Return Convert.ToInt32(locNewAxis)
```

The result of the given data should be 39.6, but I'm unable to obtain it.

Comment: Please use the image upload tool on Stack Overflow rather than a shortened URL to a OneDrive location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution - Based on the information of @meowgoesthedog

```
Dim locNewAxis = 0.5 * (180 / Math.PI) * Math.Atan(locFraction)
```

This last code line did the trick. 
THX

Comment: Mark it as answered then.